# How to validate single lines in Html TextAreaFor against regular expression(s)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, textarea

I am stuck with the following problem. On a web page in my current C# / MVC project, I added some control elements to fill a model. Among these control elements is a text area, designed using `@Html.TextAreaFor`:

```html
<div class="smt-textarea ">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Numbers):
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m. Numbers, new
                {
                    @class = "form-control",
                    id = "smt-textarea",
                    rows = 25,
                })

            </div>
```

Users should enter a sequence of numbers into that text area. The number sequence follows a specific pattern. The pattern is later evaluated in code-behind methods, which are working well, and which are not part of my question here.

As a new feature, the numbers entered in the text area should now be validated regarding the amount of numbers in the actual sequence. The rule states that only digits from `0-9` can be entered in the text area. A number sequence should consist of exactly 19 digits.

Since I need to directly access the text area, I figured it might be a good idea to opt for Javascript in this particular case. I should note that I am quite new to JS and this might be one part of the problem. Be that as it may, based on some posts here on SO, I came up with the following preliminary solution.

```js
console.log(textArea.value);
    var reg = /\d{19,19}/;
    let regex = new RegExp(reg);

    if (regex.test(textArea.value)) {
        console.log(regex.test(textArea.value));
        alert("IT'S A MATCH !!!");
    } else {
        alert("SORRY, NO MATCH.");
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("smt-textarea");
    textArea.onkeyup = function (evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;

        if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
            validateTextArea(this);
        }
    };
};
```

Unfortunately, the code seems to validate the entire text area, meaning I do get a match whenever there are one more digit sequences matching the pattern, e.g. when entering the following

```
12345
0276114931111401167
skjfsjgrs
ksgfskgjsgjsrgs
```

`skjfsjgrs` and `ksgfskgjsgjsrgs` are valid because they are preceded by a "valid" number sequence.
What I would like to accomplish is that upon pressing the `<ENTER>` key, only the current line of the text area should be validated against the regular expression outlined in the sample. If the current line does not match, a warning message should be displayed. Once the user corrected his/her digit sequence, validation should continue moving to the next line until the next error pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your validation will be passed if your string from text area contains a sequence from 19 numbers. In order to make sure each line is valid you'd better use `^` and `$` [anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions) to match the whole string from start to end. Something like this:
`/^(\d{3}\n?)*$/`

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById("smt-textarea");
textArea.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;

  if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
    validateTextArea(this);
  }
};

function validateTextArea(textArea) {
  let regex = new RegExp(/^(\d{19}\n?)*$/);

  if (regex.test(textArea.value)) {
    alert("IT'S A MATCH !!!");
  } else {
    alert("SORRY, NO MATCH.");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="smt-textarea" rows="25"></textarea>
```

Also it might be a good idea to trim your string value in order to avoid problems with white-space characters in the end.

**Update**

Here is another version which validate line by line:

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById("smt-textarea");
textArea.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;

  if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
    validateTextArea(this);
  }
};

function validateTextArea(textArea) {
  let lines = textArea.value.trim().split('\n');
  let regex = new RegExp(/^\d{19}$/);
  let invalid = lines.some(function(line, index) {
    let lineInvalid = !regex.test(line);
    if (lineInvalid) {
      alert(`Line ${index+1} is invalid`);
    }

    return lineInvalid;
  });

  console.log(`Text area is ${(invalid ? 'invalid' : 'valid')}`);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="smt-textarea" rows="25"></textarea>
```

Comment: I had a feeling that there was something odd about the regular expression. Although an improvement, running your code snippet with the  sample entries from my original post did not produce the intended results. If first enter `12345`, the result is fine, continuing with `0276114931111401167`, I'll get a no match. Upon entering the remaining strings (i.e. `skjfsjgrs`, `ksgfskgjsgjsrgs`), I'll get a `NO MATCH`. It appears that after a `NO MATCH`, the following sequences are automatically treated as `NO MATCHES`, too.

Comment: Yes, my current regular expression validates input from the textArea as a whole. So if at least one line is invalid then the whole validation will fail. I suppose another way is to split your input string into multiple lines and validate them one by one. But anyway how are you going to prevent user from entering a new line after typing an invalid one?

Comment: Well, I guess, at the moment, I cannot prevent users from entering a new line after an invalid one. I tried applying some sort of buffer, i.e. `var textAreaBuffer = textArea.value.split("\n")`; then checking the last item using `var lastBufferItem = textAreaBuffer[textAreaBuffer.length - 2];` It is frustrating that there seems to be no easy solution. I guess I need to change my angle. I was considering applying some sort of grid view with a single column, checking each row individually and only then have the grid add the new line automatically. But that's only theory. Other suggestions?